# Expired FB Token

Tags: ios, facebook

I currently develop an iOS app that uses FB Connect to enable login. In the past 2 months, I have gotten at least two reports of users who are unable to login to our app. It turns out the solution was for them to go to Settings->Facebook, click on their account and relogin. I'm guessing the access token is expiring for some users.

Why is the iOS system level token not automatically refreshing when needed? Is there some way for my app to initiate this? Or at least some way to alert a user to this case so they can fix it themselves?

And why aren't more people seeing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to handle this in your app yourself. Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors#auth and check the login error scenarios. There's also some sample code included.

Also, you could have a look here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0#sessions

Comment: Do you know which error I am missing? I am already handling the standard Auth errors (e.g. FBErrorLoginFailedReasonSystemDisallowedWithoutErrorValue, FBErrorCategoryAuthenticationReopenSession, etc.) but I need to know which one is being used for this particular case. That way, I can tell the user to relogin to Facebook in Settings (or maybe I can refresh the token from my app?) Thanks for the help!

Comment: I believe this bug has something to do with this: